# AWS Account: Can't log in due to email clash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been given an AWS account and the task to update the Billing and Account information, such as email and password.
Surely, I have done as required and updated the email address of the amazon account from abc@example.com to xyz@example.com, as well as changing the password.

Now when I try to log in, I get logged into xyz@example.com, **a different, pre-existing** account with the same password that I did not know existed. It is also owned by us, I guess someone created it and forgot about it (I was given the password to use, I personally wouldn't have reused the password).

The problem is that all my EC2 instances are running on the abc@example.com account, into which I can no longer log in.

I am surprised amazon did not warn me when I changed the log-in information.
How to I get access back to abc@example.com?

Comment: If someone generates a password for a new account.. and ends up with a password used for a different account before - then your password generation/management procedure is **seriously** flawed.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But can't state it often enough!

Answer (score 1):

On the AWS login page you can enter an email address to login as the root user of an account, or an account ID to sign in as an IAM user. You should enter an account ID if you have any with admin rights. Once you're in you can contact AWS support to help resolve this, and raise it as a bug. I don't think you can solve this yourself.

If you can't solve this then log into the account you can access and contact Amazon support - they should help you get access to your account without a support contract.

[image: AWS login]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while ago, and Amazon couldn't help me. I ended up changing my main email on Amazon.com, used the new email to log in as the root user, and then managed the accounts from there. Then, I changed my Amazon.com email back.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this was actually surprisingly easy.
All I had to do was change the mail address of the original xyz@example.com that I still had access to to ijk@example.com.
Now I can access both accounts again!